# Including useContext hook causes child's useState to reset to initial value

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks, react-router-dom

I've been struggling with this problem for a few days, so any help would be greatly appreciated. We have a global data context which we're including in a few components in the hierarchy. I've replicated the issue we're seeing in the basic example below.

You can also [run it on CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-franklin-69kty)

The problem is that `childValue` in the `Content` component is reset to its initial `useState` value every time the component re-renders. But this is *only* the case when the `useData` context is included up the chain in the `Routes` component. Removing the `useData` line (and hardcoding `isAuthenticated`) solves the problem. This is not an acceptable solution, however, because we need to be able to keep certain values in a global context and include them wherever.

I have tried wrapping stuff in `React.memo(...)` to no avail. What am I missing here?

```js
import React, { useState, useContext, useEffect } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import { render } from "react-dom";

// Routes

const Routes = () => {
  // We see desired behavior if useData() is removed here.
  //  i.e. Initial Value does NOT get reset in Content
  const { isAuthenticated } = useData();
  // const isAuthenticated = true // uncomment this after removing the above line

  const RouteComponent = isAuthenticated ? PrivateRoute : Route;

  return (
    <Switch>
      <RouteComponent path="/" render={props => <Content {...props} />} />
    </Switch>
  );
};

const PrivateRoute = ({ render: Render, path, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    path={path}
    render={props => <Render isPrivate={true} {...props} />}
    {...rest}
  />
);

// Data Context

export const DataContext = React.createContext();
export const useData = () => useContext(DataContext);
export const DataProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);
  const [contextValue, setContextValue] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsAuthenticated(true);
  }, []);

  const doSomethingInContext = () => {
    setTimeout(() => setContextValue(!contextValue), 1000);
  };

  return (
    <DataContext.Provider
      value={{
        isAuthenticated,
        doSomethingInContext,
        contextValue
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </DataContext.Provider>
  );
};

// Page Content

const Content = props => {
  const { contextValue, doSomethingInContext } = useData();

  const [childValue, setChildValue] = useState("Initial Value");

  useEffect(() => {
    if (childValue === "Value set on Click") {
      doSomethingInContext();
      setChildValue("Value set in useEffect");
    }
  }, [childValue]);

  return (
    <div>
      <div style={{ fontFamily: "monospace" }}>contextValue:</div>
      <div>{contextValue.toString()}</div>
      <br />
      <div style={{ fontFamily: "monospace" }}>childValue:</div>
      <div>{childValue}</div>
      <br />
      <button onClick={() => setChildValue("Value set on Click")}>
        Set Child Value
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <DataProvider>
      <Router>
        <Routes />
      </Router>
    </DataProvider>
  );
};

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is this: when you call `doSomethingInContext` it triggers `setContextValue` (after the timeout). When that runs, it updates the `Provider`'s data, which causes `Routes` to rebuild (since it is a consumer). Rebuilding `Routes` changes the `render` function, causing everything underneath to get thrown away and rebuilt. Try `useCallback`: in `Routes`, add this:

```js
// In the body...
const render = useCallback(
  props => <Content {...props} />,
  []
);

// In the RouteComponent
<RouteComponent path="/" render={render} />
```

That way, the function doesn't change, and the children should be preserved in the rebuild.

Comment: This fixes my issue, thank you! The trouble I'm seeing now is that down-the-chain components are not rendering/updating sometimes. Is there a general pattern for a component to "opt in" to updating without user interaction?

Comment: I'm not sure I can answer that without more explanation. You can opt-in to updates of a context by using `useContext`.

Comment: Thank you—we are using `useContext`. We just have to be more surgical about `props` now.